# "soft focus" effect in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I was looking for an implementation of "soft focus" effect with **php** and **GD**

More info here: http://www.nickgallery.com/web_pages/technical%208.htm

Tutorial in photoshop: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-awesome-soft-focus-effect-photoshop-2/

I was trying to do with something like that:

```
<?php
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
  imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
  header("content-type: image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) - it has a lot of great filters/options built into the library that might help you get this sort of result.

[Here's](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php) the demo page where you can see some of them in action.

Answer (score 1):

You'd most likely have better luck using [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) and scripting it to achieve this, otherwise you're looking at doing a LOT of per-pixel manipulation with GD, which is going to be a slow operation in PHP>

Comment: Putting it to ImageMagick in a shell process would be a good idea, perhaps?

Comment: Sure, if IM's got a soft focus filter. Either way, GD's the equivalent of MS Paintbrush, and soft focus is a bit out of its league

Comment: what about imagefilter(); ? Maybe it's just need some combination of different filters?

Comment: Possibly, problem is that soft focus is the combination of multiple different filter types. blurring, brightness, etc.. with multiple versions combined into a single one. it's possible, but do you want to go through the pain of recreating it.